# WiFi between two houses 50 meters apart with line of sight

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am a developer from Stackoverflow, but I am also quite bad at the hardware stuff. Recently I came into a need to have Internet in a house that is 50 meters away from where my ADSL modem is. Since I've never done any work with computer hardware, nor do I have experience in networking, I am kindly asking for your advice on how to achieve this.

There is a direct line of sight between the two houses. I am not sure what equipment to buy and how to set it up.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If your modem isn't also a wireless AP (check it's page to see if there isn't the option to enable wireless) you can buy a wireless router and an Ethernet cable (if you wish to have your computer wired). Signal loss occurs mostly because of concrete walls, so consider buying a few meters of Ethernet cables and not using wireless at all if you have too many walls between the PCs. A workaround is to place some aluminum foil behind the antenna to "boost" the signal - which in my experience actually "boosts" it about 20%. You can also ask your ISP if you can't have a second AP on the other house.

Comment: 50 meters is a huge distance for most access points.  If you are able to place the wireless access point right next to a window you might be able to do this.  Lets not even get into the fact you didn't indicate what type of 802.11 connection you are using.

Comment: You need to avoid low-cost wireless routers or access-points that have omni-directional and/or built-in/fixed/non-removeable antennae. You probably have to upgrade the antenna to an outdoor directional antenna at each house, and connect the outdoor antenna to the WAP with a SMA connector and cable through the wall.  The directional antenna is a weak form of physical security (i.e. potential intruders off to the sides see a much weaker signal) and focuses signal xmit & receive to the intended target.

Comment: [Some basic info on 802.11 antennae](http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/wifi_info.html).  50 meters is certainly do-able if WiFi crackers can build a [DIY long-range antenna](http://home.eng.iastate.edu/~gamari/CprE537_S11/project%20reports/Homebrewed%20Long-range%20802.11.pdf) good for over 7 miles!

Comment: @sawdust Yagi antennas for wifi can be bought for pretty cheap.